# ServiceStack CustomRegistrationFeature

Tags: c#, authentication, server, authorization, servicestack

I'm new in ServiceStack library. I want to write my CustomRegistrationFeature with custom field and add it to ServiceStack as a Plugin. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to just take a copy of the [existing RegistrationFeature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/RegistrationFeature.cs) plugin including its [RegisterService](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/RegisterService.cs) and [Request/Response DTOs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/381e31d9f0e90afdba796180188be011fe3bb58f/src/ServiceStack.Client/AuthDtos.cs#L56-L84) then modify it to suit your needs.

You'll want to rename the existing DTOs to avoid ambiguity with the built-in Registration Service.

Before you do that I'd check to see if use the OnRegister [Session or Auth Events](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions#session-events) can handle the customization that you need.